# How to route to a page on a server not at the root in react router

Tags: react-router

Lets say I have a page on a server which I want to run react on.
For example

**myreactpage location on site**

- *site.com/path1/path2/myreactpage.html*

**react router**

```js
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={Home} />
        {/* doesn't work */}

        <Route path="/path1/" element={Home} />
        {/* doesn't work but I expected this */}

        <Route path="*" element={Home} /> 
        {/* doesn't work  */}

        <Route path="/path1/path2" element={Home} />
         {/* doesn't work */}

        <Route path="/path1/path2/myreactpage.html" element={Home} />
         {/* doesn't work */}
       
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

I get console warning as follows:

> index.js:77 No routes matched location "/path1/path2/myreactpage.html

Comment: Are you trying to link to an external site/page from the React app? Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do here? Also, without any other context, the `element` prop takes a `ReacNode`, a.k.a. JSX, it should probably be `element={<Home />}`. Maybe you have something like `const Home = /* some JSX literal */` though?

Comment: @drewreese  No. A website that already exists I want to run react on a page inside it.

Comment: `react-router` only concerns itself with routing/navigating to pages within the React app. If you are linking to anything ***outside*** the React app then use a regular anchor tag.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I know. I am. The point is though if my react app does not sit at the root of the hosted server = ie www.mysite.com/index.html then it has problems routing to itself. Ie if its at www.mysite.com/somepath/somepath/index.tml it cannot route even to itself unless I specifically set the first route NOT to /  but instead to /somepath/somepath/index.html

Comment: Check out the `basename` prop on the router, it exists for this exact purpose when the app is being served from a sub-directory. It's unclear what that has to to with linking to external resources though.

Comment: @DrewReese well spotted. This looks like the better solution.

Comment: @DrewReese It turns out after trying this method it didn't work. Even for the links. So my solution is the only one that works.

Comment: Ah, well ok. It's still not clear to me what exactly you are trying to link to. Glad you have a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I have resolved this. **I was wrong**
It does work if I add this path

```js
<Route path="/path1/path2/myreactpage.html" element={Home} />
```

However, it needs a hard refresh (I hadn't cache busted it)
Also it won't work on webpack-devserver. Which is fine, because I can extend it with express to capture that path.